# Why is Google Scripts' JSON.parse method converting numbers to floats?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a Google Script code to manage some data in Google Sheet. I'm pulling data from external API and every time I receive numbers in JSON response they're converted to floats by JSON.parse available in Google Script.

Example:

```
const test = '{ "numericValue": 0 }';

JSON.parse(test)
```

Result: `{numericValue=0.0}`

```
const test = '{ "stringValue": "0" }';

JSON.parse(test)
```

Result: `{stringValue=0}`

It doesn't happen with browser JSON.parse method.
Is there any way to fix this besides converting all numbers to strings before parsing?

Comment: there is no integer type in javascript, All are numbers, you can test then if they are integer or not `Number.isInteger()` this is alll documeted !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logger has always done that.  But the console doesn't.  Don't know the issue but you get use to it.  Don't worry about it

```
function floatTest() {
  const obj='{"value": 0 }';
  console.log(JSON.parse(obj));
  Logger.log(JSON.parse(obj));
}


Execution log
8:28:00 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:28:00 AM  Info    { value: 0 }
8:28:00 AM  Info    {value=0.0}
8:28:01 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: You're right, it turns out this is just a Logger issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to verify that what you are saying is wrong:

```js
const test_1 = JSON.parse( '{ "val": 0 }')

console.log ('test_1', typeof test_1.val, Number.isInteger(test_1.val) , test_1.val )

const test_2 = JSON.parse( '{ "val": "0" }')

console.log ('test_2', typeof test_2.val, Number.isInteger(test_2.val) , test_2.val )
```

Comment: OP is saying this happens in Google Apps Script, not the browser.

Comment: @adiga I think it's just a matter of the default format for cells in Google Sheet. The JS engine  is will always remain the same whatever the execution environment = there is no integer type in JS, just numbers =

Comment: When you log values with console.log it's as you say but if you use built in (in the Apps Script) Logger than it logs incorrect values.

Comment: @SomeRandomGuy As Cooper's answer explains, it's the Logger method that shows this kind of information. but the REALITY is still there, there is no integer type in javascript ENGINES, and its JSON.parse method will always return a type of number for number in a JSON description, and will never transform an integer to float (when the value has no comma), as you falsely believe